# I get numbers instead of values when I iterate over the keys of my javascript dictionary in a jQuery app

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

[A simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metaperl/n2J7z/1/) does exactly what I would expect when I iterate over the keys of an object.

However, when I write a similar snippet [here](https://github.com/metaperl/vcpaste/tree/master/paste/2011-09-17-11-52-11/app) in [index.html](https://github.com/metaperl/vcpaste/blob/master/paste/2011-09-17-11-52-11/app/index.html#L59), I get back integers instead of the keys themselves.

I apologize for showing actual code, but I dont understand why a simple test would do what I want and the "complex" case would not... unless something about jQuery is changing something?

Comment: Also, have you looked at the actual JSON?  Are you sure that what you are expecting to be a category is actually a name of something, not a number?

Comment: Don't apologize for giving us actual code. :)  Here, we're all programmers, and we're here to answer real questions, about actual written code. Here if you *don't* post actual code the first comment will usually be, "Can you please post the code already?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an `Array`, a special Object whose keys are `integers`.

```
Object.keys({a:0}) instanceof Array; // true
```

So it's not [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For...in) the object but the Array of keys.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is that for .. in is not a construct to iterate over an array (like it is in Perl/Python). Instead it is a way to get the keys of what I got the keys of.

Comment: Tersely stated and it took some head-scratching and going back and forth to the references you generously listed, but I finally got it :)

Comment: underscore.js is my new friend. it does the things I thought I was doing with Javascript :)

Comment: underscore is great and lightweight too

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your json contains an array.  If you are creating a "dictionary" from an array than the keys would be the indexes, so they would be numbers.  You could still use these keys to access the elements of the object like:

```
obj[key] = value;
```

Where `obj` is the array, and `key` is the index.